# ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 for Google Apps

Tags: saml, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Can we use Google custom SAML App as idp with ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2? I have created a Google SAML app but didn't know how to find `ACR Url` and `Entity ID`.
Is there any brief example to implement SSO in ASP.NET with Google SAML App?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use Google as an IdP, if that is what you are trying to do?

I do not have an example.

Comment: Can you share the link?